# Avoid unintentional editing of variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game, and therefore have some variables I'd like people to not be able to see or mess around with.

Right now I can go in the developer console and just type

```
myVariable = 9999
```

and it's changed.

I am trying to do most serverside, and just display the data on the client side, but I still need some crucial variables.

So what are some good ways to handle that other people meddle with my code?

Comment: Even if you made it a local variable, they could just take the debugger and set a breakpoint. The client can do whatever it wants, and can never be fully trusted.

Comment: If you want to prevent people from "breaking" their own game: that's impossible; it's code running on their computer, they can do with it whatever they want. If you are sending high scores back to the server and want to prevent people from cheating: wrong approach; the server just gets an HTTP request (or whatever) and has absolutely no way of knowing where that came from; preventing cheating in this scenario is a lot more complex than preventing fiddling with a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from changing game values in the browser console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590690/prevent-user-from-changing-game-values-in-the-browser-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### short answer:

You can't do this!

#### long answer:

You can do different things to prevent a variable to be editable. For example in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) you can use the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword to create an immutable variable.

You could also define an immutable property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'immutable', {writable: false, value: 12});
obj.immutable; //12
obj.immutable = 13;
obj.immutable; //12
```

But what you can *never* do is to prevent the user to change this behaviout of his browser. Thats not even hard in most cases. A simple browser plugin could just redefine `Object.defineProperty`. Its a limitation of client side code that you will never be able to prevent the user from editing it.

In the end he can always just download your JS code, edit it and run it again.

This is why all criting things like validations must be checked on the server! And additional validation on the client is maybe useful, but never secure!

Answer (score -1):

If this is in an object, you may use the [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) function to make it immutable.